# Сделать линукс-библиотеку видимой для QT-программы

Tags: linux, qt

Необходимо запустить Qt-программу, имея ее исходный код. Но при запуске в QtCreator выдается ошибка `'cannot find -lpcap'`. В линуксе данная библиотека стоит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зависимости к данной библиотеке в .pro-файле следующие:

```
unix {
    LIBS += lpcap
}
```

Каким образом расшарить линуксовую библиотеку, сделав ее видимой для  Qt-программы? Не изменяя исходный код и, желательно, не используя интеренет - на рабочем месте его нет. Просто, расшарить либу. Возможно некая линковка, читал про нее, но так и не разобрался...

Comment: libpcap0.8-dev нужен наверное

Comment: Т е достаточно изменить в .pro файле "LIBS += lpcap" на зависимость "LIBS += libpcap0.8-dev"?

Comment: нет, установить пакет, на картинке в самом низу, или просто libpcap-dev, короче пакеты с "-dev" это для разработки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При линкове либы вы забыли черточку (которая отрезает префикс `lib`). Должно быть так:

```
unix {
    LIBS += -lpcap
}
```

Иначе линковщик ищет либу `lpcap.a`, а не `libpcap.a`